# smaple wordpress plugin header not showing my plugin in admin panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hi i want create wordpress plugin and create smaple plugin
my plugin start by comment but my plugin not show in wordpress admin panel (wp-admin/plugins.php)
my comment is :

```
/*
* Plugin Name : smaple_plugin
* Description : create smaple plugin
* Author : rafael
* version : 1.0.0
*/
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh I had this problem .
It is easy only remove space after each comment title( Plugin Name , Description , ... ) and test this

```
/*
* Plugin Name: smaple_plugin
* Description: create smaple plugin
* Author: rafael
* version: 1.0.0
*/
```